# Rails API versioning - Invoke a controller action if it exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, api-versioning

Right now I have two API namespaces, Api::V1 and Api::V2

I plan on implementing V2 slowly over time rather than all in one shot. However, since part of it exists, I'd like it if the client could send all HTTP requests to the V2 URL and let the server deal with it if that particular endpoint is not yet implemented.

Is there a way to route V2 requests to the V1 controller if the V2 controller does not have an action?

Simple Example:

routes:

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
        resources :items, only: [:index]
    end
    namespace :v2 do
        resources :items, only: :create
    end
end
```

will produce the following endpoints:

1. GET  /api/v1/items
2. POST /api/v2/items

The goal is to send a GET request to /api/v2/items and have it invoke Api::V1:ItemsController#index since the V2 controller does not have this method yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace :api do

    namespace :v1, path: "v2" do
        # All endpoints that are on v1 of API
    end

    namespace :v2 do
        # All endpoints that are on v2 of API
    end

end
```

If you run rake routes here you'll see that they all match the route "api/v2/____#_____" but the ones in the top block invoke Api::V1 actions and the bottom block invoke Api::V2 actions, so youll have to move them from the top to the bottom as you implement those endpoints

Answer (score 0):

I also have a versioned API. I haven't bumped to the next version yet. But I thought I'd share what I *plan* to do. This might be a little hairballed. And I have a feeling that this will be more useful to me (to think through my plan) than it is to you. So, sorry about that. But, here goes...

Before I start, I should say that I take a different sort of approach to my controller actions. In my apps, I like to delegate my controller actions to plain old ruby objects that I call 'managers'. Every controller has a 'manager_base'. So, in my controllers, I have something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  private

  def do_action(action=nil)
    action ||= caller[0][/`.*'/][1..-2]
    manager.send("manage_#{action}", self, cookies, request)
  end

  def manager
    base = self.class.name.split('::')
    base.pop
    base << "#{controller_name.camelize}Managers::ManagerBase"
    base.join('::').constantize
  end

end 

class Api::V1::FooController < ApplicationController

  def index
    do_action
    render_result
  end

end
```

And then I also have:

```
class ManagerBase
  class << self

    def manage_index(controller, cookies, request)
      sub_out("Index", controller, cookies, request)             
    end

    def manage(controller, cookies, request)
      new(controller, cookies, request).manage
    end

  private

    def sub_out(method, controller, cookies, request)
      sub_manager(method).manage(controller, cookies, request)   
    end

  end # Class Methods

  def initialize(controller, cookies, request)
    @controller = controller
    @cookies = cookies
    @request = request
  end

end

class Api::V1::FooManagers::ManagerBase < ManagerBase
  class << self

    private

    def sub_manager(method)
      "Api::V1::FooManagers::#{method}Manager".constantize
    end  

  end # Class Methods
end

class Api::V1::FooManagers::IndexManager < Api::V1::FooManagers::ManagerBase
  def manage
    ... do stuff
  end
end
```

If you follow the bouncing ball, here's how my application flow goes:

- `index` gets called on `Api::V1::FooController`
- `index` calls `do_action` (inherited from `ApplicationController`) which, in turn calls `manager` (also inherited from `ApplicationController`)
- `manager` returns the `Api::V1::FooManagers::ManagerBase` class
- `do_action` then calls `manage_index` on `Api::V1::FooManagers::ManagerBase`
- `manage_index` calls `sub_out` which in turn calls `sub_manager`
- `sub_manager` returns the `Api::V1::FooManagers::IndexManager`
- `sub_out` then calls `manage` on `Api::V1::FooManagers::IndexManager`
- `manage` (the class method - inherited from ManagerBase) creates a new instance of `Api::V1::FooManagers::IndexManager` and then calls `manage` (the instance method) on the new instance.

As may or may not be apparent, when I move to Api::V2, I have two opportunities to 'hook' back into the Api::V1 versions of my managers (which is equivalent to using my V1 controller methods - your original question).

First, if I haven't implemented `Api::V2::FooManagers::ManagerBase` yet, I can cause `ApplicationController.manager` to fall back to the last implemented version of `ManagerBase` (i.e., `Api::V1::FooManagers::ManagerBase`). In which case I'll be using all of the `Api::V1::FooManager` sub managers (like `IndexManager`).

Second, if I've implemented `Api::V2::FooManagers::ManagerBase` but have not yet implemented `Api::V2::FooManagers::IndexManager`, then I can cause `Api::V2::FooManagers#sub_manager` to fall back to `Api::V1::FooManagers::IndexManager`.

Okay, I'm going to stop now. Thanks for the opportunity to think this through out loud. Apologies if it's a totally useless, hot mess.

Comment: Wow! that is one hell of a scheme!  it turns out I was able to solve my problem by using the :path option when namespacing an api module, and now i just need to move the controller actions from v1 to v2 as they are completed

Comment: Well, thanks. I guess. I hope it doesn't get me into trouble down the line. How and where do you use the :path option?

Comment: too much for a comment,  i posted it as an answer check that out